# Trouble with ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString()')

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I have a trouble when trying to get URL where my swf file is showing with

```
    ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString()')
```

method.

For example: **domain 1:** contains SWF and **domain 2:** contains html file with embed sourcecode.

So if domain 1 = domain 2 it works perfect and I get needed URL. If not - I get "undefined".

How could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your embed/object HTML tag's "**allowScriptAccess**" attribute to "**always**"

Comment: Thx a lot. But could I get that URL if I havent access to html file?